# How to match on multiple fields per array item in elastic search

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I am trying to create an elastic search query to match multiple fields inside of an object inside of an array.

For example, the Elastic Search structure I am querying against is similar to the following:

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "titles",
                "_type": "title",
                ...
                "_source": {
                    ...
                    "genres": [
                        {
                            "code": "adventure",
                            "priority": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "code": "action",
                            "priority": 2
                        },
                        {
                            "code": "horror",
                            "priority": 3
                        }
                    ],
                    ...
                },
                ...
        ]
```

And what I am trying to do is match on titles with specific genre/priority pairings. For example, I am trying to match all titles with `code=action` and `priority=1`, but my query is returning too many results. The above title is hit during this example due to the fact that the genre list contains both a genre with `code=action` AND another genre that matches `priority=1`. My query is similar to the following:

```
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must":[
                            {"term": {
                                    "genres.code": {
                                        "value": "action",
                                        "boost": 1.0
                                    }
                            }},
                            {"term": {
                                    "genres.priority": {
                                        "value": 1,
                                        "boost": 1.0
                                    }
                            }}
                        ]
                    }                    
                },
                ...
            }
```

Is there any way to form the query in order to match a title with a single genre containing both `priority=1` AND `code=action`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have recreated your problem. I added the following mapping

```
PUT titles 
{
  "mappings": {
    "title": {
      "properties": {
        "author": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "genres": {
          "type": "nested"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I added values to the index. This was what was inserted

```
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "titles",
        "_type": "title",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "author": "Author 1",
          "genres": [
            {
              "code": "adventure",
              "priority": 2
            },
            {
              "code": "action",
              "priority": 3
            },
            {
              "code": "horror",
              "priority": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "titles",
        "_type": "title",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "author": "Author 2",
          "genres": [
            {
              "code": "adventure",
              "priority": 3
            },
            {
              "code": "action",
              "priority": 1
            },
            {
              "code": "horror",
              "priority": 2
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "titles",
        "_type": "title",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "author": "Author 3",
          "genres": [
            {
              "code": "adventure",
              "priority": 3
            },
            {
              "code": "action",
              "priority": 1
            },
            {
              "code": "horror",
              "priority": 2
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

My query is:

```
GET titles/title/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "genres",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "genres.code": {
                  "value": "horror"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "genres.priority": {
                  "value": 1
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The query returns

```
        "_source": {
          "author": "Author 1",
          "genres": [
            {
              "code": "adventure",
              "priority": 2
            },
            {
              "code": "action",
              "priority": 3
            },
            {
              "code": "horror",
              "priority": 1
            }
          ]
        }
```

This title is the only one that has code = 'horror' and priority = 1.

Comment: This is the correct solution. The keyword I was looking for for both mapping and search was `nested`.

Comment: I was looking for this `nested` solution for a while and never get there. Thanks a lot Leandro to help me out with this!

Comment: Excellent level of detail. Thanks.